# ECONNREFUSED error with express and websockets

Tags: javascript, express, websocket, econnrefused

I am new to the world of web development. I am using HTTP endpoints to authenticate a user with JWT Tokens and I am also using the same tokens for authenticating the WebSocket connection as I am trying to implement real time chat functionality. I am getting ECONNREFUSED error when I am trying to test my websockets with Insomnia What could be wrong?

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const authRoutes = require('./routes/AuthRoutes');
const chatRoutes = require('./routes/ChatRoutes');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/UserRoutes');
const wsManager = require('./utils/WebSocketManager');
const Authenticate = require('./middleware/Authenticate');

// Load environment variables
dotenv.config();

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/chatapp';

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Express app and middleware
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// Use the authentication and chat routes
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use('/chat', chatRoutes);
app.use('/users', userRoutes);

// Create HTTP server and WebSocket server
const server = http.createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// WebSocket connection handling
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  const token = new URLSearchParams(req.url).get('token');
  
  // Verify the JWT token
  Authenticate.verifyWebSocketToken(token)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
      // Add the decoded token to the WebSocket object
      ws.user = decodedToken;

      console.log('Client connected');
      wsManager.addUser(ws);

      ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log(`Received message: ${message}`);
        const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message);
    
        if (parsedMessage.type === 'private') {
          wsManager.sendMessageToUser(ws, parsedMessage.to, parsedMessage.content);
        } else {
          // Handle other message types or broadcast to a room
        }
      });

      ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
        wsManager.removeUser(ws);
      });


      // Send an initial message to the connected client
      ws.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: 'info',
          message: 'WebSocket connection established.',
        })
      );

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('WebSocket authentication failed:', error.message);
      ws.close();
    });
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I have tried putting websockets to different port and it did not worked I have also checked the port using lsof -i :4000 and there is one listen from node as it should be and I have correct URL on Insomnia as

```
ws://localhost:4000/token='tokengoeshere'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by WSL when switched to Windows everything worked fine